# How to handle callback responses in Ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

In my Node.js application I want to call some async function in Ejs code and render the result. I tried:

```
<ul>
<% setTimeout(function () { %>
<% supplies = [1, 2, 3, 4]; %>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
<% }, 1000) %>
</ul>
```

But it seems it doesn't work. Why doesn't it work and how I can fix it?

Comment: Why do you need to do this, because this will not be possible in EJS. It's a template engine to it just renders everything into HTML. It can't have set timeouts or async calls.

Comment: I basically don't have access to the Node.js code in this context and in the ejs file I run my custom stuff. I speculate that making my file sync would work. But why doesn't it work with async calls?

Comment: Because that's how ejs works :)

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Got it. I ended by deasyncing the function and it's working fine. I posted an example as answer. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that Ejs doesn't support such a feature, but what we can do is to *deasync* the function using the [`deasync`](https://github.com/abbr/deasync) module.

```
<% function foo (timeout, callback) { %>
<%     setTimeout(function () { %>
<%          callback(null, [1, 2, 3, 4]; %>
<%     }, timeout); %>
<% } %>

<% var Deasync = require("deasync") %>
<% var fooSync = Deasync(foo) %>

<ul>
<% supplies = fooSync(1000); %>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
<li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
<% }, 1000) %>
</ul>
```